# VBA snippet to surpass macro settings notification

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am planning to have a do while loop, to open 100+ .xlsm files inside a directory. But .xlsm files have macro setting notifications that pops up after opening the file. The macro settings in the Trust Center is grayed out, and I don't want to change it since I'm working on corporate files. It's okay if I pick any option between disable or enable macro, I just to open each file, copy a row and close it.

Comment: Did you try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` When opening the files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Application.Automationsecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
```

for example to disable macros, or use `msoAutomationSecurityLow` to enable them.

Answer (score 1):

With `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` you can use `Application.EnableEvents = False` too.